# How to compare two integer object?

Tags: java, integer, integer-arithmetic

```
Integer i = new Integer(0);
Integer j = new Integer(0);
while(i <= j && j <= i && i !=j ){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Why does this while loop execute?
I understand that `i != j`. But separately, both `i <= j` and `j <= i` returns true. Why? And doesn't that mean that `i == j`? In that case the while loop shouldn't execute even once. But it goes for an infinite loop. Why is this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `==` can be performed between two references (and is, when both sides are `Integer`), `<=` can't - so the compiler unboxes. So, your code is equivalent to:

```
while (i.intValue() <= j.intValue() &&
       j.intValue() <= i.intValue() &&
       i != j)
```

Now when `i` and `j` refer to different `Integer` objects with the same value, all of those conditions will be met - hence the loop keeps executing.

Comment: So even though mathematically, == and <=, both seems to  be similar in comparing the quantity of things being compared. In Java it is not so!! Any idea why so? Why does == compares references and <= focuses on the actual quantity (intValue)? From a general perspective, it looks pretty odd. To be honest, I thought <= must be comparing hashCodes in some way!!

Comment: @shanti: Well, if you use `int` instead of `Integer`, everything will be fine. Whenever you have operands of reference types, `==` will compare *references* rather than contents - it's as simple as that. While Java could have been changed to make `==` unbox where appropriate, it would have been a breaking change - the `==` comparison has been valid since Java 1.0, meaning a reference comparison just like between any other two references.

Comment: makes sense. So basically, in case of wrapper classes, == or != checks for references, but <= or >= checks for actual primitive values contained in the object. Thanks a lot for responding swiftly and clearly. :)

Comment: the operator "==" works on both primitive and object types. so when it works on objects it check for the memory reference of objects but the "<=" is  just a simple arithmetic operator which works  only on the primitive data

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
while(!i.equals(j))
```

You are comparing two integer objects with == rather than two primitive int values. That is to say, "Integer" is an object while int is a primitive value. Doing != on an object will return true for Integer(0) and Integer(0) because they are indeed not equal -> each has a separate location in memory.

The "new" operator allocates dynamic memory on the heap. 
For == to work, you could change the type to int, as in:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

This will compare the values directly.

If you use "Integer," another alternative is to use the .compareTo method, which will compare the value of the objects

Answer (score 0):

`==` for objects, like a capital-I `Integer`, compares references.  `<=` and `>=` will unbox the `Integer` objects and compare the values numerically, which is completely different.

Think of `==` and `!=` in this case as completely unrelated to the values of the `Integer`s.

Answer (score 0):

"<=" is comparing the values while "!=" the references hence here all the cases are true hence it is going in infinite loop.